# Select Case Not Or

Tags: vba, excel, select-case

I'm looking to carry out a Select Case with just one case - where the case is not equal to "P", "Ev" or "Af".

This is what I have so far.

```
Select Case Range("my_range").Offset(0, column_offset).Value
    Case Not "P", "Ev", "Af"
        'my code
 End Select
```

The case could equal 50 different values and I want the same action (under `'my code`) to be performed for all of them unless the result is P, Ev or Af.

I've also tried `Not "P", Not "Ev", Not "Af"` along with replacing `,` with `Or` but to no avail.

The response each and every time is:

> Run-time error '13': Type mismatch.

I know I could replace this with an if statement along the lines of...

```
If Range("my_range").Offset(0, column_offset).Value <> "P" And Range("my_range").Offset(0, column_offset).Value <> "Ev" And Range("my_range").Offset(0, column_offset).Value <> "Af" Then
    'my code
End if
```

but I'd prefer to use the Select Case option if I can.

Any thoughts anyone?

Many thanks

**EDIT**

I should also say I did try using

```
Select Case Range("my_range").Offset(0, column_offset).Value
    Case "P", "Ev", "Af"
        Exit Select
    Case Else
        'my code
End Select
```

but the error message:

> Compile error: Expected: Do or For or Sub or Function or Property

kept popping up.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You cannot use `Not` in this way. But you can refactor to

```
Select Case Range("my_range").Offset(0, column_offset).Value
    Case "P", "Ev", "Af"
        'ignore this
    Case Else
        'my code
 End Select
```

Comment: I have just added an edit that says that I tried to add add 
`Exit Select` (where you've written `'ignore this`) which didn't work, but of course all I need is to just not enter code and the next line will move on and exit the select!
Clearly one of those days...!  Thanks for your help. :)

Answer (score 1):

I know this question were asked a long time ago, but today I stumbled across the exact same wonder: -Could you use a Select Case Statment with a `Not` Operator?

Neither have I found that `Not` can be used, But instead this method could be used:

```
Select Case [variable]
    Case is <> [condition 1]
        'my code
End Select
```